# How to call a pop-up window SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, url, swiftui

Hi) Can you please tell me how to call the popup window correctly? I watched various videos without JSON unloading everything works, but how to unload a model from the network. gives out various errors. Can you show an example or source where it is explained how to do it correctly? I'm just a beginner) I apologize for posting so much code, but it makes more sense. I don't understand what properties and how to set them correctly in the code.

here is my code

```
struct Dish: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let price, weight: Int
    let description: String
    let imageURL: String
    //var tegs: [Teg]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, price, weight, description
        case imageURL = "image_url"
        //case tegs
    }
}

class MenuVieiwModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var dishViewModel: [Dish] = []
    
    private var bag = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    func fetchMenu() {
        let urlString = "https://run.mocky.io/v3/aba7ecaa-0a70-453b-b62d-0e326c859b3b"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("ERRRROOOOOOORRRRRR")
            return
        }
        
        URLSession
            .shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .tryMap { res in
                guard let response = res.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else {
                    throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
                }
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                
                guard let menu = try? decoder.decode(DishResult.self, from: res.data) else {
                    throw URLError(.badURL)
                }
                return menu.dishes
            }
            .sink { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    print("AllGood")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] returnedMenu in
                self?.dishViewModel = returnedMenu
            }
            .store(in: &bag)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var menuDetails: Dish
    @Binding var showDetail: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            VStack {
                
                Spacer()
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading,  spacing: 16) {
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .top) {
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                            
                            ZStack {
                                
                                AsyncImageView(url: URL(string: menuDetails.imageURL)!)
                                    .padding()
                                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                                    .frame(width: 311, height: 232)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                
                                HStack(spacing: 20) {
                                    
                                    Button {
                                        
                                    } label: {
                                        
                                        Image(systemName: "heart")
                                            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                    }
                                    .padding()
                                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                    .background(Color.white)
                                    .cornerRadius(8)
                                    
                                    Button {
                                        
                                    } label: {
                                        
                                        Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                    }
                                    .padding()
                                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                    .background(Color.white)
                                    .cornerRadius(8)

                                }
                                .padding(.leading, 170)
                                .padding(.bottom, 120)
                                
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    Text(menuDetails.name)
                        .font(.callout)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                    HStack(spacing: 10) {
                        
                        Text("\(menuDetails.price)")
                            .font(.caption)
                        
                        Text("\(menuDetails.weight)")
                            .font(.caption)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray.opacity(0.4))
                    }
                    
                    Text(menuDetails.description)
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                
                Button(action: {}) {
                    
                    Text("Добавить в корзину")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .frame(width: 311, height: 48)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                
            }
            .padding()
            .padding(.leading, 4)
//            .padding(.bottom)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(width: 350, height: 446)
            .background(.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30 , style: .continuous))
            .shadow(radius: 30)
        }
    }
}

struct MenuView: View {
    @StateObject var menuViewModel = MenuVieiwModel()
    @State var tegs: Teg = .всеМеню
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var backButton
    @State var showDetail = false
   
    var title: String

    var columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 15), count: 3)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            NavigationView {
                
                VStack {
                    
                    //NavBarMenuView(title: title)
            
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        
                        HStack(spacing: 10) {
                            
                            ForEach(menuViewModel.dishViewModel) { teg in
                                
        
                            }
                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                        
                        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 15) {
                            
                            ForEach(menuViewModel.dishViewModel) { menu in
                                MenuItemsView(menuItems: menu)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                        backButton()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }

                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text(title)
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image("avatar")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                    }
                }
            })
            .onAppear {
                menuViewModel.fetchMenu()
            }
//            DetailView(menuDetails: Dish(id: 1, name: "Pizza", price: 45, weight: 230, description: "fdfdfdfdfdfd", imageURL: "pizzaPodarok", tegs: []), showDetail: $showDetail)
//                .onTapGesture {
//                    self.showDetail.toggle()
//                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get, and on which line of your code?
 You say `I don't understand what properties and how to set them correctly in the code.` 
 explain what that means, which properties, where do you `set` them?

Comment: If I try to specify DetailView under NavigationView and put menuViewModel.dishViewModel into it, it gives out the following error Cannot convert value of type '[MyDish]' to expected argument type 'MyDish' If I specify var detail: MyDish, it says Missing argument for parameter 'detail' in call in TabBar, but I don't need that either. I tried doing properties in DetailView like this for example var title: String, but it will also return Missing argument for parameter 'detail' in call

Comment: `menuViewModel.dishViewModel` is an array of `[Dish]`, you need to specify **one** `Dish` to pass to your
 `DetailView`. So, try something like: `if let dish = menuViewModel.dishViewModel.first {
 DetailView(menuDetails: dish, showDetail: $showDetail)
     .onTapGesture {
         showDetail.toggle()
     }
}` to pass the first `Dish` to `DetailView`.